# What right does SO have to not let me leave when I choose to?

Tags: support

I've just tried to close my SO account and got this:

> Hello,
>
> You recently sent a request to have your Stack Overflow profile
>   removed.
>
> We're sorry to see you go! This email is just to let you know your
>   request
>
> has been received, and we will respond with help ASAP.
>
> Thanks,
>
> The Stack Exchange Team

Why is it that I can't leave right away? I've been a good member of Stack Exchange sites for quite a few years and it strikes me as a bit odd, that when I decide to leave that my decision needs to be reviewed.

Can anyone explain why the wait **is required**?

---

As @John Caswell pointed out there is a similar question. I'm not interested in the wait time. My question has to do with the propriety of making someone wait to review their reasons to leave.

My title was edited by someone to remove the allusion to Hotel California, but this is really the case. I joined SO thinking it was a good thing. Now I don't think it is and I want to leave. But just like in the Hotel California I find I can't.

It's odd that my decision to leave is not respected.

I would still like to thank those of you who have voted this post up, and to those who have voted it down... you're welcome!

Comment: "Why is it that I can't leave right away?" Because "**I've been a good member of Stack Exchange sites for quite a few years**". They not only want you to be sure, but that the deletion process doesn't have harmful side effects that the rest of us will have to deal with.

Comment: Yeah, I know that @Braiam. But honestly, I have already thought it over many times. Perhaps they should change the exit policy to **Are you really, really sure**. But what are the harmful side effects? I just want my decision to leave to be respected.

Comment: So you've been here a few years, then thought it through a few times, but now granting even another day gets you upset? What part of the notification indicated your "decision to leave is not respected"?

Comment: And maybe a moment to reflect and to put the brakes on something might be better than getting all upset over a silly python question of all things.

Comment: To answer the headline question, *"What right does SO have"*: it's their site, they can do what they like. You're welcome to walk away and not come back, but if you want them to delete your account you have to follow their process.

Comment: There is no fundamental "right to delete things" in any jurisdiction that I'm familiar with. (Particularly given what you've made a legally binding agreement to do with regards to the content of your posts under creative commons license).  The current process is a good compromise and a much better offer than many other sites make. What you get when you do delete is a real, hard delete too, unlike many other sites.

Comment: @Flexo The closest thing I can think of is [the right to be forgotten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_be_forgotten). But even that is in regards to damaging information tied to an individual's real name and says nothing about how fast the removal has to happen. SO's process certainly sounds faster than Google's.

Comment: @mario what makes you think I'm upset? You know perfectly well you can't assume that.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but if you want to leave, just... leave.  Change your notification preferences so you stop getting any e-mails you might be receiving, log out and don't come back.

Answer (score 40):

We require a wait because there are quite a few users out there who just plain get angry about something and jump to the "I'm deleting my account" option without thinking it through very well. The deletion gets processed and they disappear, but doing so quickly overlooks some common problems around user deletion:

1. They might have just needed some cool down time. Sometimes users request deletion and then a short while later realize they just got a little hot-headed and don't *actually* want to delete their profile, they just needed to walk away from that particular situation.
2. They might not want to lose all association from their posts. We reinforce what will happen for higher-reputation users, and some users try to request deletion of all their posts along with the deletion of their profile. When they realize all of their posts will remain on the site and that their name will just be taken off all of them, they opt not to delete their profiles and instead just stop using the site - keeping content attribution is rather important to some people.

The biggest concern is that *after* the profile has already been deleted, some users run into this problem:

3. They want their user profile to be restored, but now it's too late. If we rushed the deletion process, then the user didn't get the *chance* to reconsider, and now there's nothing we can do for them but to tell them "you gotta start over." We do not, under any circumstances, restore content from profiles if they were deleted by user request.

Even if you managed to get a response from us quickly, we still only **schedule** profiles for deletion - we do not ever immediately delete them. Your profile will wait for a 24-hour countdown period, during which you can cancel the deletion at any time from your profile page and after which your profile will then be eligible for full deletion - it will be deleted the next time the account cleanup process runs.

Comment: Then there's issues of accounts getting hacked; preventing permanent damage from a compromised account is relevant.

Comment: I already applied for deletion now that I've been given the chance. @animuson, you can't lump everyone together by saying that quite a few users out there just plain get angry and then treat them all the same. That's why SO should not lump me into the general category of a cool off period. I don't need one. I made up my mind and I've decided to stick to it. I can assure you I don't want my profile to be restored.

Comment: @r3mnant So you're asserting that SE should read people's minds, and see into the future to determine whether or not they're really sure they want to delete their account, that they are the owner, that they won't change their mind upon reflection, that they've already reflected on it, etc?  If SE invents a time machine and a mind reading device I'd honestly expect them to have better uses for it than allowing a handful of users to skip a 24 hour wait period before deleting their account.

Comment: @r3mnant Every site out there has varying policies on how they handle deletions, but almost *none* will process a deletion request immediately. Many will give you the *appearance* of a deletion being processed immediately by simply hiding everything by you temporarily until the actual deletion occurs. Even Facebook does this - they simply hide you from the world but don't actually delete your profile until 14 days after the request is processed. Our process is fairly expedited compared to other services. Immediate account deletion only causes future problems, which is why no one does it.

Comment: The solution is simple: change the rules so next time, everyone has to wait except r3mnant, because he's the one from which you know for super sure he's made up his mind and is not hacked.

Comment: jeez people... If I want to leave a site they send me a confirmation email to my email address on record, if I respond to that email then my account wasn't hacked. Then they take me off. What is so hard to understand about that? Or will Servy say that someone could have hacked into my account, changed my email address, then attempted to delete my account? But then, for that scenario SO could wait... and even send emails to both accounts. You're missing the point I made earlier. And, so everyone understands, there are other people in my position as well. I'm speaking for those people too.

Comment: So SO is similar to Uber in this case